# How to check in openssl c++ if a string is a certificate, and if so, if that string is root certificate

Tags: c++, validation, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm working on gcc environment. I need to implement two functions:

1) function that checks if a given string is a certificate.

2) function that checks if a given string is root certificate.

I want to use openssl.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. consider the functions [`d2i_X509` and related](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_X509.html#).
2. Technically, a root certificate is any certificate trusted by the application without further verification. So it is up to you as to which certificates are root certificates. By convention root certificates have their issuer and subject names identical. You can get the issuer and subject names from an X509 certificates with the

   `X509_NAME *X509_get_subject_name(X509 *a);`
     `X509_NAME *X509_get_issuer_name(X509 *a);`

and compare them with the

```
int     X509_NAME_cmp(const X509_NAME *a, const X509_NAME *b);
```

method.